# xsubpp compiler not present

Tags: linux, perl, redhat

I have a RedHat Linux Enterprise Server.   When I try to install the Perl package `DBI` from cpan, it is failing because it is not able to find the `xsubpp` compiler under `ExtUtils`.  The exact error message is :

```
ExtUtils::MM_Unix::tool_xsubpp : Can't find xsubpp at /home/user/perl/lib/perl5/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm
```

My question is: How does the `xsubpp` compiler get installed? Should it have come as part of any Perl package installation OR Is it something which we should get along with the OS installation.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=728393

Comment: @choroba : I did not get xsubpp in /usr or /usr/bin. Also when I try to install ExtUtils::ParseXS, I get the same error of missing xsubpp.

Comment: RedHat breaks Perl. Install your own Perl aside the system one.

Comment: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fxsubpp&submit=Search+...&system=fedora&arch=

Comment: thanks for your help. When I install, I get error stating : "perl-devel is needed by perl-ExtUtils".  What is perl-devel? Tried googling, not clear

Comment: probably another package?

Comment: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-devel&submit=Search+...&system=fedora&arch=

Comment: thanks a lot choroba.. will try and keep you updated..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is asking for the RPM package

yum install perl-devel
or 
dnf install perl-devel

it seems that the ExtUtils::ParseXS module has been splitted to that package

Comment: it is in perl5-devel on freebsd too